# Does the Arctic Circle Theorem have anything to do with the geographical Arctic Circle?

Tags: combinatorics, terminology, circles

Does the [Arctic Circle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aztec_diamond) Theorem have anything to do with the geographical [Arctic Circle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arctic_Circle)?

Comment: It looks like a play on words such as "frozen" and "top" rather than anything geographic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No - the analogy is with the tiling in those parts of the region outside the arctic circle being "frozen" in place.

This is the [paper that introduced it](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9801068.pdf).  In particular, none of the authors are from the far north (they were at Michigan, MIT, and Bell Labs), and there's not some progenitor of the work that was either.    I mention this because, for example, [tropical geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropical_geometry) is so-called in honor of a Brazilian author.

Also, Jim Propp (one of the authors) wrote a blog post [My Life with Aztec Diamonds](https://mathenchant.wordpress.com/2021/01/16/my-life-with-aztec-diamonds/) that is somewhat discursive and seems like the natural place for him to mention such a connection, and he does not.